# Basic question about the properties of dimension of an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am learning about the dimension of an algebraic set and I have a couple of questions I am hoping to resolve to have a better understanding.

Let $V$ be an algebraic set in $\mathbb{C}^n$, defined by polynomial equations $g_1, ..., g_m \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n]$, where we may express
$$
V = V_1 \cup ... \cup V_r,
$$
where each $V_i \ (1 \leq i \leq r)$ is an irreducible component of $V$. 
Let $I$ be the ideal generated by  $g_1, ..., g_m$. Then I know that 
$$
\dim V = \dim_{Krull} \mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n] / I.
$$

I have two questions on this.

1) Given any $i \ (1 \leq i \leq r)$, does it always follow that
$$
\dim V = \dim V_i ?
$$

2) Is it always the case that 
$$
\dim V = \max_{1 \leq i \leq r} \dim V_i?
$$

I feel like 2) may be true but not 1). I would appreciate any input on this! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are correct, 1) is not true, 2) is. Just as an example try $n=2$, with coordinates $x,y$ and $V$ defined by  $x(x-1)= xy=0$.

Comment: You are correct! :) Regarding 1): Consider, e.g., the case where $V$ is the disjoint union of a point and a (complex) line in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Regarding 2): This follows directly from the definition of "dimension (of a topological space)" and the definition of "irreducible component".

Comment: I see. That is good to know. Thank you for the clarification. Greatly appreciate it!!